# Optional parameter in SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I have a user defined function which is used in many stored procedures which will return me some value. If it possible for me to add a new optional parameter to the same.

If I don't pass any value it should be null and if I pass some value it should take it. I don't want to go and change all the stored procedures to do so.

Example code

```
dbo.CalculateAverageForUser(userid int)
```

Can I use `dbo.CalculateAverageForUser(userid int, type NVARCHAR(10) = NULL)`

Comment: If you post code or XML, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code" button (101 010) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you don't want to go adjusting all of your existing stored procedures that reference the function then I think you would need to create a new function with the code from your existing one

```
CREATE FUNCTION CalculateAverageForUser2
(
    @userid int,
    @param2 nvarchar(10) = NULL
)
RETURNS float
AS
/*Code from existing function goes here*/
```

Then just change the existing function to the following

```
ALTER FUNCTION CalculateAverageForUser 
(
 @userid int
)
RETURNS float
AS
BEGIN
RETURN dbo.CalculateAverageForUser2(@userid, DEFAULT)
END
```

Answer (score 3):

I think the easiest way is to make a stored procedure CalculateAverageForUserAndType(int userid ,type NVARCHAR(10)) Put your original code inside the new procedure. Then change CalculateAverageForUser to

```
dbo.CalculateAverageForUser(int userid)
AS
BEGIN
    EXEC CalculateAverageForUserAndType userid, NULL

END
```

This way you can slowly migrate to your new stored procedure and your old one still works.

Comment: This should do nicely. Shame you can't overload, as well as use default parameters. But then SQL isn't C++ ....

Comment: This won't work. You can't call stored procedures from within functions.

Comment: same idea still but then with functions.