# Passing default values of parameters to Table Valued Functions

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
create function Xtest
(@d1 varchar(3)=null
,@d2 varchar(3)=null)
returns table 
as
return 
with code_list(code_pattern)
as
(
    select x.code_pattern
        from (values (@d1),(@d2)) as x(code_pattern)
        where x.code_pattern is not null
),y
as
(
    select substring(code,1,3) as code
        from tblicd
        where substring(code,1,3) in 
        (
            select * from code_list
        )
)

select * from y
```

is my function which will make sense when it's fully finished.  If I try to run this query and I don't supply two parameters, it will fail.  I have the same code as a stored procedure and if I only enter one parameter, it works fine and assigns the second parameter null.  Is there a way that I can pass `null` as a parameter value if the parameter isn't supplied, like one can do with stored procedures?

The function does compile.

Comment: Related, at least one is probably a dupe : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3278860/optional-parameter-in-sql-server ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12721869/alter-a-sql-server-function-to-accept-new-optional-parameter ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8358315/t-sql-function-with-default-parameters

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You can't omit the parameters when you call a function. This isn't anything you're doing wrong in the syntax, it's just simply not supported by SQL Server. Stored procedures have optional parameters, but functions do not.

You can, however, supply `default`:

```
SELECT code FROM dbo.Xtest(default, default);
```

Or in this case if you know the defaults are `NULL` you can do:

```
SELECT code FROM dbo.Xtest(NULL, NULL);
```

Also [please always use the schema prefix](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/11/bad-habits-to-kick-avoiding-the-schema-prefix) (in this case `dbo.`) when creating and referencing any object, *especially* functions.

Comment: I knew there had to be a way.  Do you know of any particular reasoning why the behavior is different between sprocs and TVFs?

Comment: @wootscootinboogie I don't know *why*, no, sorry.