# Previous Race Details using Current date and or driver id as a variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

So I have a table (table A) with a list of drivers and the races they entered and their finishing position

Fields are

```
Date of race
Driver id
Finishing position
```

I want to create a left join query where I can have the above 3 fields and then then joined on them the previous race that the driver entered and its date , finishing position

So a table that has the headers below…………

```
Date of race | Driver id | Finishing position | prev race date | prev race id | prev finishing position
```

I want it to only return the previous and not races prior to the last race

I want to use the date and or driver id as my variable that I will use to input prior to running query.

Any support or thoughts would be grateful

FYI - i am using SSMS 2008

Comment: You may find this link useful to make your question clearer: http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: Do you want just one row, like you are specifically looking for one driver or do you want all the drivers and you are looking for an exact race date and then all of those who participated in that race and their previous race?

Answer (score 0):

```
 With thisRace as (
      SELECT *
      FROM TableA
      WHERE driver_id = @driver_id
        AND race_date = @race_date 
 ),
 previousRace as (
     SELECT TOP 1 *
     FROM TableA
     WHERE driver_id = @driver_id
       AND race_date < @race_date 
     ORDER BY race_date DESC
 )
 Select 
     T.race_date, T.driver_id, T.finish_pos,
     P.race_date, P.race_id,   P.finish_pos
 FROM thisRace T, previousRace P
```

**[HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3278860/optional-parameter-in-sql-server)** is also a question using optional parameters and maybe help you with your follow up question

Comment: Juan thanks for this, im not expert at SQL, but shoudl i not be declaring the @driver_Id and @race_date? also if i want the query to either use the animal id or the race date as the prompt (not both) would this query work?

Comment: A) Yes, you need declare both variable, but that wasnt your question. Maybe you declare the variable in the beginning of the function or inside. But I has to assume you have some basic sql knowledge otherwise you should start with a basic tutorial. For example I cant explain how `select` work or write a `cte` and those are also requirements. The idea is we help with the specifc or all the question will be very long. B) No, this wouldnt work right now you probably have to add some `and/or` and conditional to see which one is null but again that wasnt part of the question.

Comment: Read [**THIS**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to know how to ask better question. Or [**THIS**](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL08903FB7ACA1C2FB) tutorial if you want learn more sql

Comment: I include a link in my answer to a sample of how create an optional paramater. Hope that help.

Answer (score 0):

This gets you a list of all drivers and their previous race.

```
DECLARE @drivers table (DriverID int, RaceDate datetime, Position int)

INSERT @drivers values(1, '9/1/2015', 2)
INSERT @drivers values(2, '9/1/2015', 5)
INSERT @drivers values(3, '9/1/2015', 9)
INSERT @drivers values(1, '10/1/2015', 1)
INSERT @drivers values(2, '10/1/2015', 2)
INSERT @drivers values(3, '10/1/2015', 10)
INSERT @drivers values(1, '8/1/2015', 8)
INSERT @drivers values(2, '8/1/2015', 4)
INSERT @drivers values(3, '8/1/2015', 2)


declare @DriverID INT = 1
declare @RaceDate datetime = '10/1/2015'

;with MainRace as (
SELECT * from @drivers where RaceDate = '10/1/2015'
),
PrevRaceDate as (
SELECT DriverID, max(RaceDate) as RaceDate from @drivers
where RaceDate < @RaceDate
group by DriverID
),
PrevRace as (
select * from @drivers d
where exists 
    (select 1 from PrevRaceDate where
     d.DriverID = PrevRaceDate.DriverID and d.RaceDate = PrevRaceDate.RaceDate)
)
Select mr.RaceDate, mr.DriverID, mr.Position, pr.RaceDate as PreviousRaceDate, pr.Position as PreviousPosition
From MainRace mr
left outer join PrevRace pr on mr.DriverID = pr.DriverID
```

Comment: Sean thanks for this its amazing, just one enhancement if you can help . i only want the last race the driver entered in and completed ie finishing position above 0, the above sql brings that the last race even if its finishing position is 0, i tried to add a filter in saying when finishing position is above 0 however it came back with null against the driver. seems like it just looks at last race and not beyond that race. for example if the drivers last race he finished 0 i would want the previous race to that one as that is technically the last race which he completed. hope that makes sense

Comment: Sean - i was able to figure it out by adding a criteria in the main race table and the prevracedate table thanks for your time. on another note maybe you can help , i want the query to be felxible with its variable input, i want to either enter driver id and get all the races for the driver ignoring the race date field or enter the race date and get all drivers that raced on that day ignoring the driver id field input

Comment: Glad you got it working! I don't think this query will be able to split the two result criteria your looking for. You will need two queries. This query is designed to bring back just one row per driver. You should ask another question and give an example of how you want the data to look.